# Do I need to always pull the id field when using react relay

Tags: graphql, react-relay

I am curious if I have to always include the `id` field when making queries to a relay graph QL server?

For example:

```
users_connection {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        userId
        firstName
      }
    }
}
```

I sometime use the `id` field as a component key when looping on results, but generally speaking I don't use it. Does relay use this under the hood on the client to perform caching?

I have tested removing this from my queries and haven't notice a difference to my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

relay-compiler adds it automatically to any type that has an `id` field even if it hasn't been explicitly requested. But you still need to add it if you actually use it in your own code.